# What are the best use cases for using Clojure for new development?

Tags: clojure

Why should I choose Clojure over another language for a new project?  In what areas does it excel?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some scenarios where I would use Clojure:

- You are building a new, **highly concurrent** application that needs to scale reliably. In my opinion, Clojure's concurrency features (STM, immutability-by-default, lock free MVCC) are the best of *any* major language at present. [Rick Hickey's excellent video](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Value-Identity-State-Rich-Hickey) about Identity and State is a great way to get a feeling for this.
- You are a Java-based shop that wants a **productive dynamic language** that can be used for rapid development or scripting while maintaining your **investment in a large Java code base**. I've found Clojure pretty effective at "gluing together" Java code since the interop capabilities are extremely good (and simple!).
- If you want to use a **functional programming language** Clojure is pretty good (it's not quite as "pure" as Haskell but has all the key features - first class functions, higher order function composition, immutability, laziness)
- If you work in a field where there is a major need for code manipulation (compilers, DSLs, natural language processing, genetic programming), where the **LISP "code is data"** philosophy enables you to be extremely productive. This is a sweet spot for [homoiconic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) LISP based languages in general.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of providing exactly the sort of reductive non-answer that Devin is referring to: I chose Clojure because I like the functional programming style and Clojure lets me do that on the JVM and interop with lots of existing code that runs on the JVM.

So the question then becomes: Why functional programming?

Immutable state - lack of side-effects, easier testing, better support for concurrency (and, in future, parallelism).

Small, functional components that can be easily reused and composed to construct large, flexible systems.

Answer (score 1):

it's very hard to find clojure developers so I would stay away from it if you work for a big company and stick with java or .net. it's more a political than technical decision in large companies. if however you are building your own product then clojure is very fast to develop in and can get you to market faster.

Comment: That's a bit of a chicken and egg scenario tho' - if no one adopts Clojure, it's hard to find developers. If more companies adopt it, there will be more developers in the market. Given that Lisp / Clojure has essentially no syntax to learn, the core function documentation is excellent (and there are several great books about Clojure) and the concepts, once mastered, apply almost uniformly across every part of the language, I'd say it's a pretty easy language to pick up and/or cross-train developers in.

Comment: Yes, its true that the language has a small syntax and is easy to learn. I think once Clojure gets a killer framework like the  equivalent of Ruby's Rails or a large company like IBM doing projects using Clojure, then it will grow alot faster and be üsed in more large companies.

Comment: You can always introduce Clojure as a "Java library for enhanced concurrent programming".... :-)